# Text-mode tool to view audio input level

Tags: audio, console, microphone

When monitoring audio input (microphone or line-in) using Audacity, I can see the current input level.

How can I monitor the input and see the level in a text console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `arecord` and `sox` command you can record a sample of 1s and measure its level:

```
arecord -qd 1 file && sox file -n stat
```

Here's an example of output:

```
Samples read:              8000
Length (seconds):      1.000000
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.992188
Minimum amplitude:    -0.992188
Midline amplitude:     0.000000
Mean    norm:          0.093221
Mean    amplitude:    -0.015338
RMS     amplitude:     0.232947
Maximum delta:         0.617188
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.001067
RMS     delta:         0.009643
Rough   frequency:           52
Volume adjustment:        1.008
```

If you're only interested in the level/maximum amplitude you can pipe the result to `awk` to only output the second field of the fourth line:

```
arecord -qd 1 /tmp/rec.waw && sox /tmp/rec.waw -n stat 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} NR==4 {print $2}'
```

And if you want to monitor its evolution you can put this command in a while loop:

```
while :; do
    arecord -qd 1 /tmp/rec.waw && sox /tmp/rec.waw -n stat 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} NR==4 {print $2}'
    sleep 1 # repeat every one second
done
```

Output:

```
0.992188
0.023438
0.046875
0.375000
0.523438
0.109375
0.242188
```

If you want the output to be in dB you can calculate it with `awk`:

```
while :; do
    arecord -qd 1 /tmp/rec.waw && sox /tmp/rec.waw -n stat 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} NR==4 {db=20*log($2)/log(10); printf("%0.4f\n",db}'
    sleep 1 # repeat every one second
done
```

Output in dB:

```
-12.6467
-13.4366
-13.2010
-14.4959
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way to convert this output to decibels, preferably in real time?

Comment: Just edited the answer by adding the conversion in dB.

Comment: thanks a lot!! Sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sox`. Example with Pulseaudio and my webcam as source:

```
sox -S -t pulseaudio alsa_input.usb-046d_0809_23E942AD-02.analog-mono -n stats
```

Also works with ALSA devices, you can specify a default device, etc. See `man sox` for details. Use `pactl list short sources` for a list of Pulseaudio sources.